C++ 11 Сборка Мусора и Обнаружение Утечек на Основе Доступности
Изучаю С++ 11 по документу:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/11
В документе есть раздел - Сборка Мусора и Обнаружение Утечек на Основе Доступности и ссылка на этот раздел:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BC.D1.83.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B0
Я заглянул в раздел и как правильно понял - раздел про умные указатели - share, weak, unique ptr. Поправте меня если ошибаюсь.
Мне не понятно почему напротив этого раздела в таблице С++11 (первая ссылка) все залито красным цветом? Что значит красный цвет? Как я сделал предположение- красный цвет значит нет поддержки данного свойства? Но как нет поддержки если share,weak, unique ptr ввели в С++ 11?
На данной странице (первая ссылка) две таблицы:
Основные возможности языка C++11
и вторая таблица:
Возможности библиотеки C++11
Я правильно сделал предположение что первая таблица касается С++ вторая STL? Уточните мне пожалуйста о чем данный раздел и что значит красная заливка в таблице Основные возможности языка C++11?

Ну никто так и не реализовал сборку мусора в C++ (и слава Богу!)...

Нет, это раздел "Сборка Мусора и Обнаружение Утечек на Основе Доступности", а не умные указатели. В этой категории были функции типа declare_reachable, undeclare_reachable, на которые вендоры компиляторов положили болт. И все это было выпилено в С++23. @Harry " никто так и не реализовал сборку мусора в C++" - консервативный сборщик мусора Боема для С++

Вы говорите "положили болт" :-) потому и красная полоса в этом месте в таблице? Но почему в сл. таблице "Возможности библиотеки C++11" раздел Сборка Мусора и Обнаружение Утечек на Основе Доступности (поддержка библиотеки) - по ссылке поддержка библиотеки открываются share, weak, unique ptr?

Потому что страница по ссылке содержит еще кучу всего помимо cборки мусора. Эти страницы на cppreference по категориям формируют, а не по документам, менявшим стандарт.

@user7860670 Это, так сказать, внешнее :) На уровне компилятора, в соответствии со стандартом это не сделано — как видно из таблицы.
